# Flutter dispose MethodChannel

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins

Is there a way to dispose a `MethodChannel` / `EventChannel` when there is no need for it?
I am asking because i want to create multiple method/event channels for objects.

Example:

```
class Call {
 ... fields ...
 MethodChannel channel;

 Future<void> answer() {
   return channel.invokeMethod('@answer')
 }
}
```

For each `Call` object i want it to have its own channel, so i can send messages to the native part without having 1 method channel that handles all the logic of the calls.

Is it recommended to use 1 channel?

**Thanks**.

Comment: I had a similar question. There is a native error that happens when coming back to the app for some reason ```Unable to merge the raster and platform threads.
'
    r0  00000000  r1  00001f72  r2  00000006  r3  b36e9b70
    r4  b36e9b84  r5  b36e9b68  r6  00001c45  r7  0000016b
    r8  b36e9b80  r9  b36e9b70  r10 b36e9ba0  r11 b36e9b90
    ip  00001f72  sp  b36e9b40  lr  f2391c9f  pc  f2391cb2```

Answer (score 3):

The channel itself is just a wrapper around a name with convenient methods to work with `BinaryMessenger`. Only when you set a callback with `setMethodCallHandler` that the callback (and likely your object) is *hold* by the messenger, and you must call `setMethodCallHandler` again with `null` for it to release your object.

Thus, you can create and use as many as channels you want, as long as they have different names, no dispose needed. However, when you *listen* to method call with `channel.setMethodCallHandler(yourCallback)`, you need to call `channel.setMethodCallHandler(null)` when you are done to avoid leaking your callback.